# Bounds on representations via (non-positive) binary quadratic forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Suppose that for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we know that there are $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2-dy^2=n$ for some $d\in \mathbb{N}$. Can we say anything about how large $x$ and $y$ are compared to $n$ (say if they are minimal among all such representations)? For positive binary quadratic forms, we can obtain some trivial bounds, but here any bound is non-obvious to me.

I am especially interested in the case where $n$ is prime. For instance, when $d=2$, algebraic number theory tells us that $p$ prime may be written as $x^2-2y^2$ if and only if $p\equiv\pm 1\mod 8 $, but the proof I have seen is ineffective.

Comment: For integer $d > 0$ not a square the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is infinite so from one solution $ x^2-dy^2=p$ you get infinitely many solutions $X^2-dY^2 = p$ and hence $\max(|X|,|Y|)$ is unbounded

Comment: That is good to know but do you know anything about the minimal solutions?

Comment: Let $a = x+y \sqrt{d} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ be a positive solution, $a^* =x -y\sqrt{d}=p/a$ its conjugate, the other positive solutions are $au,u \in U$ where $U = \{ u \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}],u > 0,uu^* = 1\}$. They satisfy $2X = au+p/(au),2Y \sqrt{d}= au-p/(au)$. So how small can be $2X$ depends on how close to $\sqrt{p}$ can be $au$, which depends mainly on $g=\min \{u \in U, u > 1\}$ the generator of $U$. This way your question becomes about the absolute value of the fundamental unit of $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ ie. its regulator which in turns depends on the class number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\vareps{\varepsilon}$

Note that if $x^2 - d y^2 = n$, then

$$(x - y \sqrt{d})(x + y \sqrt{d}) = n.$$

Equivalently, you are looking of $\alpha \in \mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ such that

$$\alpha \overline{\alpha} = n.$$

Let $S$ denote the set of solutions to this equation.
Note that if $\alpha \in S$, then $\overline{\alpha} \in S$.

Now suppose there exists
 an element $\vareps = u + \sqrt{d} v$ with $u^2 - d v^2 = 1$ with $\vareps > 1$. (There always does.)
Then its easy to check that if $\alpha \in S$ then $\alpha \vareps \in S$
and also $\alpha \vareps^{-1} \in S$, where $\vareps^{-1} = u - \sqrt{d} v$. This allows you to take a very large solution and make it smaller. The best way to measure the size of an element of $S$ is via the map:

$$S \rightarrow \{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R} \oplus \mathbf{R}, x + y = \log(n)\},
\alpha \rightarrow (\log |\alpha|, \log |\overline{\alpha}|).$$

Hence by multiplying by powers of $\vareps$ one can ensure that

$$\log(n)/2 + \log(\vareps)/2 \ge \log |\alpha| \ge  \log(n)/2 \ge \log|\overline{\alpha}| \ge \log(n)/2 - \log(\vareps)/2.$$

This gives the bound

$$|2x| = |\alpha + \overline{\alpha}| \le |\alpha| + |\overline{\alpha}|
\le \sqrt{n}(\vareps^{1/2} + \vareps^{-1/2}).$$

In the particular case where $d = 2$, one can take $\vareps = 1 + \sqrt{2}$, and $n = p$, one obtains the bound

$$x < \sqrt{p} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{\sqrt{2} - 1}}{2} \right) = \sqrt{p} \cdot  1.0986841\ldots $$

For example, out of the first 10000 primes, the closest hit is

$$321 - 2 \cdot 94^2 = 85369,$$

where

$$321 = \sqrt{85369} \cdot 1.098638\ldots $$

It turns out that the bound above (with the given constant) is optimal - you can find primes such that $x/\sqrt{p}$ is arbitrarily close to the given number. This is deeper than the inequality above, to prove it, you have to use equidistribution results of characters first proved by Hecke in 1920 using analytic properties of L-functions of characters.

In general, one has the class number formula, which gives a bound rougly of the shape

$$\log |\vareps| < d^{1/2 + \epsilon},$$

(you get a much better bound the bigger the class number is, but one expects $h  = 1$ for infinitely many $d$ so you shouldn't expect to do better than this) and so you get a general bound of the form

$$x,y \ll \sqrt{n} \exp \left( d^{1/2 + \epsilon} \right)$$

Comment: Which Hecke character do you look at to obtain results on the distribution of $\frac{Tr(\pi)}{\sqrt{p}}$, $ (\pi)$ principal prime ideal of $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$ ?

Comment: Dear @reuns, since describing Hecke characters is always annoying, let me give enough hints for you to work it out. I'll assume purely for convenience that the narrow class number is trivial, the modifications required are only technical. Consider $\alpha_v = (1,1,\ldots,1,\varpi_v,1,\ldots)
\in \mathbf{A}^{\times}_F$ where $\varpi_v$ is a uniformizer at the prime $v$. The corresponding global ideal has a generator $\varpi$ which is unique up to totally positive units $\varepsilon^{\mathbf{Z}}$. Then the character
$$\psi(\alpha_v) = \exp \left(2 \pi i \log(\varpi)/\log(\varepsilon)\right)$$

Comment: is well defined. You should now be able to guess the extension of $\psi$ to the
infinite places and thus all of the ideles. Note that $\psi$ is NOT an algebraic
 Hecke character, but that's OK. A final (important) point is to get equidistribution one needs to know not only analytic properties of $L(\psi,s)$ but also $L(\psi^n,s)$ for every positive integer $n$. Then an argument (on which Sato-Tate for higher dimensional representations is based) gives equidistribution.

Comment: Ah, you send principal ideals $(\varpi)$  to $|\varpi| \varepsilon^\mathbb{Z}$ to $\exp(2i \pi \log |\varpi|/\log |\varepsilon|)$ I had never thought to such things, tks. Then I know how to use $L(\psi^n,s)$ or [$L(Sym^n \psi,s)$](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michael.harris/Clay.pdf) to obtain Sato-Tate (it works for any Hecke character with values in the unit circle such that  $L(Sym^n \psi,s)$ has no pole at $s=1$ and for which the PNT is known)